# How to perform intersection in nodeset using xpath 2.0

Tags: xslt

I have two different node-sets that contain one or more elements with the same name.

I want to select these same-named elements by using the intersect operation in XPath 2.0 and XPath 1.0 as well.

This is the sample code i have tried.

Input:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <root>
    <child1>
    <a />
    <b />
    <d />
    </child1>
    <child2>
    <c />
    <a />
    <d />
    </child2>
    </root>
```

The code I tried

Xpath 1.0:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- TODO: Auto-generated template -->
    <xsl:variable name="ns2" select="/root/child2/child::*"/>       
    <xsl:copy-of select="/root/child1/child[.=$ns2]"/>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Xpath 2.0:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- TODO: Auto-generated template -->
    <xsl:variable name="ns1" select="/root/child1/child::*"/>
    <xsl:variable name="ns2" select="/root/child2/child::*"/>       
    <xsl:copy-of select="$ns1 intersect $ns2"/>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Issue: I am getting the empty result.

Expected result:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <a/>
    <d/>
```

Please suggest what I am missing.

I have tried the set operation intersection for two different noteset.I have attached my code sample below,

Comment: Shorter solutions exist both in XSLT 1.0 (XPath 1.0) and XPath 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not really doing "intersection" here, because all of the child elements of `child1` are different to the child elements of `child2`. Just because two elements share the same name, that does not make them the same element.

What it looks like you are after is elements under `child1` that have the same name as an element under `child2`

If you want your XSLT 1.0 solution to get results, you need to change the `xsl:copy-of` to this

```
<xsl:copy-of select="/root/child1/child::*[.=$ns2]"/>
```

Or this...

```
 <xsl:copy-of select="/root/child1/*[.=$ns2]"/>
```

However, this will return all `child1` child elements, because you are checking the value of the elements are the same, not the name. One way to do it is this...

```
<xsl:for-each select="/root/child1/*">
    <xsl:variable name="name" select="local-name()" />
    <xsl:copy-of select=".[$ns2[local-name() = $name]]" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

Alternatively, define a key like so:

```
<xsl:key name="child2" match="child2/*" use="local-name()" />
```

Then you could do this...

```
<xsl:copy-of select="/root/child1/*[key('child2', local-name())]"/>
```

In XSLT 2.0, you could do something like this....

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$ns1[some $name in $ns2/local-name() satisfies $name=local-name()]"/>
```

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks a lot. Your answer is very helpful and guided me where to correct.

Answer (score 1):

Not repeating Tim's correct remark, but just to the problem:

**XSLT 1.0** (Not possible with a single XPath expression, unless an XSLT standard function, such as `current()` is used):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="child1/*">
    <xsl:copy-of select="self::*[../../child2/*[name() = name(current())]]"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XPath 2.0**:

Use:

```
/*/child1/*[name() = /*/child2/*/name()]
```

This can be verified with the below XSLT 2.0 transformation which evaluates the expression and outputs the selected nodes:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:sequence select=
     "/*/child1/*[name() = /*/child2/*/name()]"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<root>
    <child1>
        <a />
        <b />
        <d />
    </child1>
    <child2>
        <c />
        <a />
        <d />
    </child2>
</root>
```

**both transformations produce the wanted, correct result**:

```
<a/>
<d/>
```

Comment: Thank you Dimitre for the different approach to produce the result.